# Exception: java.awt.HeadlessException in jsp

Tags: swing, exception, jetty, awt, headless

I am basically drawing a 3d chart in swings.Its working fine as standalone java application.
I integrated it with jsp,but it is throwing headless exception.I am using jetty webserver.

here is the stack trace:

```
     java.awt.HeadlessException
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:159)
at java.awt.Window.(Window.java:432)
at java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:403)
at javax.swing.JFrame.(JFrame.java:202)
at org.jfree.chart.ChartFrame.(ChartFrame.java:76)
at org.jfree.chart.ChartFrame.(ChartFrame.java:64)
at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.index_jsp:86)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:109)
```

can anybody point out what is actual error.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot,but i solved the problem by setting the below property in jsp.

```
      <% System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");%>
```

I was actually integrating this jsp in another application,may be that application is setting headless property as true,so was not getting the 3D chart.

Thanks a lot.